# typescript promise return after loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, promise

I am trying to return after all the calls to an external service are done but my code is just flying through the for loop and returning.  I cannot do a promise.all here as I need some values obtained in the loop.  Is there an easy way to do this in typescript/angular2?

```
var ret = [];
for (var l in users){
   var userLicense = users[l].licenseNumber;
   this.callExternalService(userLicense).subscribe(response=>{
      ret.push(response+userLicense);
   }
}
resolve(ret);
```

Comment: You need a combination of `promise.all()` and `map()`.

Comment: Does `.subscribe()` return a `Promise`?

Comment: the external call gets an observable from http.get request

Comment: why cant you use promise.all? in your example you don't use any returned data in the next iteration of your loop nor do you exit your loop early => map + promise.all should work just fine

Comment: What is `ret.add` supposed to do?

Comment: @guest271314 No, `subscribe` returns a `Subscription`. However, you can convert an observable into a promise if you so desire with `toPromise`.

Comment: @torazaburo ret.add should have been ret.push, I will make the edit to be clear, sorry!

Comment: @torazaburo Have noticed `.subscribe()` being used at questions, not infrequently when tried with `Promise`, though have not tried `angularjs` or `nodejs` to extent have used the methods. Are the methods associated with `angularjs` or `nodejs`?

Comment: @guest271314 They're part of rxjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are already using observables, you can use a combination of [`forkJoin`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) and [`map`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/select.md) to achieve this:

```
var ret = [];
Observable.forkJoin(
    users.map(
        user => this.callExternalService(user.licenseNumber)
            .map(response => response + user.licenseNumber)
    )
).subscribe(values => {
    ret = values;
    resolve(ret);
})
```

Comment: @torazaburo It is from the OP's code. Didn't want to change it. I assume this entire thing is wrapped inside another Promise.

Comment: @torazaburo it is wrapped in another promise, thanks for clarifying Saravana.  I will look into the forkJoin

Answer (score 1):

You could try `combineLatest`:

```
return Observable.combineLatest(
  ...users.map(user => this.callExternalService(user.licenseNumber)
    .map(response => response + user.licenseNumber)),
  (...vals) => vals);
```

This will return an observable of arrays of results from the service calls, which you can then subscribe to, convert to a promise with `toPromise` if you prefer, etc.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to do some aggregation in the loop and pass it as part of return, you can add it into a Promise.all as Promise.resolve(aggregatedData)

Something like that:

```
 function getData(ii) {
    return new Promise(res => {
      res(ii); 
     });
   }

 function getUserData(users) {
   let promiseArray = [];
   let aggregatedData = 0;

    users.forEach(user => {
      aggregatedData += user.id;
      promiseArray.push(getData(user.id));
    });
    promiseArray.push(Promise.resolve(aggregatedData));
    return Promise.all(promiseArray);
 }

 getUserData([{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}]).then(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: But he's not using promises, he's using observables.

Comment: you can do the same with Obseravble.forkJoin. Btw, his question subject is "typescript promise return after loop" - so i assumed he use promise.